# How to move through tracked person?

Tags: navigation, move-base, openi-tracker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using Openni tracker for tracking and recognizing user's gesture and i want to move through the tracked person by navigation!(I have transformed its position to the /map frame)

But the tracked person is an obstacle on the map so the navigation goals are aborting!

Is there any way that i can go near the tracked person using navigation ?

Edit:
Finally I solved my problem! i just decreased the x value of tracked human by 0.5 meters and then i sent the new goal to the navigation, and every thing is ok now!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36112/how-to-move-through-tracked-person?/) by [Alireza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1637/alireza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 717 on 2012-06-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2012-06-10**:
Can you not just put the navigation goal in front of the person? Why does it need to go "through" them... and do you really want to collide with the person, or do you want it to follow a moving person without colliding with him or her?

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-06-15**:
Please post the solution to your problem as an answer instead of an update to your question and then accept it after a week or so when you can. This way, people can easily see that the question is answered and what the correct answer is. Thanks for helping keep ROS Answers easy to use!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Edit: Finally I solved my problem! i just decreased the x value of tracked human by 0.5 meters and then i sent the new goal to the navigation, and every thing is ok now!

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-08-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-11-03**:
@Alireza im using people detection as well and i need to mark a given position as a obstacle do you have any idea how to acomplish this? would really appreciate some help , thanks